# Como instalar o autocomplete Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, autocompletar, ipython-notebook, anaconda

Como faço pra instalar a extensão que sugere o código seguinte para o Jupyter Notebook? Para o VS Code tem esse Code Runner que é muito bom, mas meus trabalhos são feitos no Jupyter. Alguém sabe?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta apertar a tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> para completar

Comment: Onde posso fazer isso? no arquivo de configuração ou no proprio .ipynb?

Comment: @BernardoLopes editei a resposta

Comment: Funcionou. Mas não é tão bom quanto o do COLAB. Sabe dizer se tem como fazer igual?